# MS-Word Cannot print customized specified pages when Table of Contents is present

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-365

I have a document that I have been working on for a few months. Today I discovered that it will not print specified pages.

**Problem**
Document cannot print specific pages if there is a Table of Contents present.

**Version**
Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14509.20000) 64-bit (running on Windows 10)

**Diagnosis**
The document does have TWO sections. I tried specifying p2s1 and it won't work.

1. Tried Open / Repair the document. No change.
2. Removed the last section so there is only one section. Still doesn't
   work.
3. Removed the Table of Contents on page 1. After doing this I am able
   to print specified pages, even if I start again with 2 sections.
4. In case it was to do with the positioning of the ToC, created a ToC
   on the last page. This reinstated the problem - i.e. cannot print
   specified pages.
5. In case the ToC was corrupt somehow, I created a new one. This
   reinstated the problem - i.e. cannot print specified pages.
6. In case it is just this document, created a new blank document with 3 separate pages & one section. Can print specified pages ok. Added a Table of Contents on page 1 - unable to print specified pages. I also tried this on another computer running [Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20164) 64-bit] with exactly same results.

**Workarounds**

1. Print from Word Online
2. Print entire document to PDF and then print desired pages from PDF reader. Not optimal.

Comment: There is currently a bug in Word for selected pages. That may be the problem. Keep your software updated and hope. You are currently using the Insider channel for updates, this is prone to be buggy.

Comment: Thanks Charles - that's a good point about using Insider Channel. I should have switched back to PROD and tested that before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to go to File > Options > Dispaly, make surethe box of "Update fields before printing" is ticked.

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post this same issue.  I checked the "Update fields before printing" checkbox as suggested by Emily and I could print any combination of pages and sections.  When a Table of Contents is present, and the checkbox has been checked, you will be prompted to update the Table of Contents AFTER you click the Print button.  I select the "Update entire table" option and everything prints as expected.

Comment: Yes this works and solves the problem for me. Thanks Emily.

Comment: This bug appears to be back or still unresolved.  I checked that box as well as "Update linked data before printing" but neither fixed the issue.  Also as far as I can tell, this document does not have a TOC but can only be printed if I print the whole document (if pages are specified the document does not print).